# Page_Load not firing in UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have created a class in c# inside a class library and i have added this control to the default.aspx, but my code doesnt fire the page_load event. Here is the code:

What am i doign wrong?

The page loads but doesn't show the label on the page. I have added the control to the page correctly without any errors. I have event added the register tag in there.

html tag: `<RandoIntegerControls:RandomIntegerControl ID="RandomIntegerControl1" runat="server"></RandoIntegerControls:RandomIntegerControl>`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CSIMedia.WebControls
{

  public class RandomIntegerControl : PlaceHolder
  {

    private Label _Label;


    public RandomIntegerControl()
    {

    }

    private void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this._Label = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(this._Label);
        this._Label.Text = "Enter random values:";

    }

  }
}
```

Default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="RandoIntegerControls" Assembly="CSIMedia.WebControls" Namespace="CSIMedia.WebControls"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <RandoIntegerControls:RandomIntegerControl ID="RandomIntegerControl1" runat="server"></RandoIntegerControls:RandomIntegerControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you include the .ascx file of your custom control in the aspx file that uses it?

Comment: no i deleted it. I havent created no ascx files. i have created this class as a class.cs file and just added this control class to the page. but i have added the default.aspx page back and i still have no luck with it.

Comment: Can you show the code where you added the control to the page?

Comment: i copied and paseted the code and it wont let me add the html, or can i do this some how, just added some of the html i dont know why?

Comment: Try using the Code Sample icon { }  To add code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from PlaceHolder, which is a Web Control and will not handle the Page_Load event. Only User Controls (.ascx) will be able to handle that event implicitly.

By the looks of the code you posted you would probably be better off using a UserControl, or if you need it re-useable across multiple projects, create a Web Control from scratch.

Comment: @clint isnt that what i have done, created a webcontrol from scratch? do u mean i need to inherit from web control for the page_load to fire?

Comment: No, to create a web control from scratch you need to inherit from Web Control itself and override the related methods to create the control. Inheriting from PlaceHolder means that functionality has already taken place.

Comment: What is it you have been asked to do exactly?

Comment: @Clint simply just to create a application that allows the user to enter random numbers and display them in asc or desc order, they have provided css and html i just need to get the functionality woroking.

Comment: @Clint thankyou, and thankyou everyone. i am oiverriding the methods and its working fine now basically i used "protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)" to fire the event. Is this ok @Clint?

Comment: Yes you can override that method to do what you specified in the code above, just make sure you call base.OnInit(e) before doing anything else so that the base classes method is called.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public RandomIntegerControl()
{
    this.Load += Page_Load;
}
```

In pages (and User Controls), the Page_Load method is normally attached automatically thanks to this attribute:

`<%@ Page ... AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`

If you don't have an aspx/ascx file, it is not going to happen automatically, but you can still hook it up manually with the above code.

Comment: when i convert this code into vb.net, everything works fine. Im a VB.Net developer but have been asked to use c# for a test project in a role i applied for, what the best way to get arround this quickly so i can get the test done quickly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. The code I wrote is C#, are you asking for a VB version?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can override `Page_Load` in the `aspx` markup file.  That file inherits from the base file.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="TestUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestUserControl" %>
```

Example to override:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

This function overrides the code-behind version.