# Loading a user control dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I'm trying to load a user control in a web service, but it doesn't execute the Load_Page().

I tried to use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, text, false);
```

But it returns a NullException. It is my code:

```
public string Controle(string url)
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(url);
        //userControl.EnableViewState = false;
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        form.Controls.Add(userControl);
        page.Controls.Add(form);
        StringWriter text = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltext = new HtmlTextWriter(text);
        userControl.RenderControl(htmltext);
        return text.ToString();
    }
```

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Where is it located? Did you have the line `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, text, false);` between the `userControl.RenderControl(htmltext);` and `return text.ToString();` lines of code?

Comment: I replace HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, text, false); with  userControl.RenderControl(htmltext); , because it was not working. But RenderControl doesnt execute the Load_Page

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the control using a method that does something like

> this.Load += Page_Load;

Please refer to this post which explains exactly what needs to be done to achieve this. Be sure to read the section stating; "***One word of caution:***" 
http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/11/05/dynamically-render-a-web-user-control.aspx
This related post will also be able to assist:
[Page_Load not firing in UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083905/page-load-not-firing-in-usercontrol)

Comment: I put this.Load += Page_Load; inside user control constructor, and it executes, but it still doesnt fire Page_Load..